# Is a compact triangulated surface obtained by edge-pairing on a polygon?

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation

I guess that one can make the compact surface by edge-pairing.
I'm trying to rearrange the triangles so that they could be considered as parts of a disk.

Let $S=\bigcup_{i=1}^n T_i$. Then we are able to reorder these triangles so that $\bigcup_{i=1}^j T_i$ and $T_{j+1}$ shares at least one edge, $e_j$. 
By using mathematical induction, I want to show the quotient space of $\bigcup_{i=1}^j T_i$ obtained after gluing $e_1,\cdots,e_{j-1}$ is a topological disk.

However there are two ways of gluing the edges. One is just gluing one edge of a polygon and that of a triangle not in the polygon. The other one is gluing two distinct edges of the polygon. How can I distinguish

How can I use the induction by integrating the above 2 ways? 
Or is there easier proof without using the mathematical induction?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just keep adding triangles while you have a disk (and recall that two triangles in a triagulation intersect ony on a vertex or on a side)

Comment: Conversely can I make a disk by removing one triangle from the surface?

Comment: Normally one uses $\text{“}\cup\text{''}$ in things like $T\cup S$ or $T_1\cup \cdots \cup T_n$ and $\text{“}\bigcup\text{''}$ in things like $\bigcup_{i=1}^n T_i$.  In displayed, as opposed to inline, settings the latter appears as $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n T_i$, with the subscripts and superscripts directly above and below the symbol.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If you remove a triangle you generally do not get a disc, as you can see immediately by considering examples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a graph which has one vertex at the center of each triangle and in which two vertices are connected iff the corresponding triangles share a side (this is called the dual graph for the triangulation)

In this graph construct an arbitrary [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree). Now cut the surface along the sides of the triangles which do *not* correspond to sides in the spanning tree. You get a disk, and clearly the surface can be reobtained by identifying things in its boundary.